# Comparing two lists in Racket

Tags: list, racket, equality

Is there a built-in function in Racket that we can check the equality of two lists in terms of only values and not the order of the values, with?

For example, it should return true if you compare '(1 2 2 3 4 5) with '(3 1 2 5 4).

Or what is the easiest way to implement such a function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the number of occurrences doesn't matter, you're doing *set comparison*. You can convert the lists to sets and then compare the sets:

```
> (equal? (list->set '(1 2 3 4 5)) (list->set '(5 4 3 2 1)))
#t
```

If the number of occurrences does matter, you're doing *multiset comparison*. A simple way to do this for common kinds of values is to sort both lists, and then compare them for equality in the usual way:

```
> (equal? (sort '(3 2 1 4 5) <) (sort '(2 1 3 4 5) <))
#t
> (equal? (sort '(1 2 1) <) (sort '(2 1) <))
#f
```

Comment: Thank you. But the problem in this solution is what if we have duplicates in our lists? e.g. comparing '(1 2 1) with '(2 1).

Comment: @Elik You didn't bother to mention duplicates in your question, and your example doesn't have duplicates. svk answered the question you asked -- and gave you two ways to do it. You could search Stack Overflow for "[racket] remove duplicates", and combine that with his answer.

Comment: @Greg Hendershott, I think that my question is a general question. and svk hadn't mentioned the second solution in the first place, he edited his comment after my comment. You don't have to write any false supposition of yours here.

Comment: @Elik It's not supposition; your question and example simply don't address duplicates. You could edit your question to provide an example with duplicates _and_ the expected/desired result in that case. If you do, maybe svg will re-answer it. (Or maybe not and you'll need to do what I suggested and search for that last piece yourself.)

Comment: @Elik: I agree with Greg here.  Include it in your question: to omit it leaves implicit what should happen.  And there are arguably valid approaches that treat duplicates as single entries!  If it's important to you, make it explicit in the question.  To put it in terms of programming: you need to present more test cases.